# PHP preg_replace Question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Having a rough time getting this working.  I convert this text:

> [url]http://www.stackoverflow.com[/url]

to

```
<a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">http://www.stackoverflow.com</a>
```

I assume that I want to use preg_replace, but I just can't get it working.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you try a regular expression evaluator that provides hints, e.g. [`RegExr`](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/). Note that the url uses the regex provided by alex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $str);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uN1K3b).

PHP does have a [BBCode parser](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php) too.

<sup>BBCode sucks... have you tried Markdown?</sup>

Comment: I'm not a huge fan of BBCode, but I really only needed barebones functionality so it works well in this case.  I wasn't aware of Markdown, so thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`$text = preg_replace("/\[url\](.*?)\[\/url\]/i","<a href='$1'>$1</a>",
  "[url]http://www.stackoverflow.com[/url]");`